# Safely store textarea input with newlines and preserve linebreaks

Tags: php, mysqli, textarea, nl2br

I have a problem storing a user submitted presentation in a database as a TEXT field. **It shall not allow any HTML whatsoever** but **should preserve the linebreaks**.

So for example if the user submits an presentation like this from a form using a textarea as input method:

This is line 1

This is line 3
This is line 4

It shall be outputted exactly like that and clean the input from any HTML in the process.

Stored procedure:

```
   if (isset($_POST['presentation'])) {
        $presentation = $purifier->purify($_POST['presentation']);
        $presentation = $mysqli->real_escape_string($presentation);
        if (strlen($presentation) > 1000) {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    else {
        $presentation = null;
    }

    if ($update_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE user SET user_presentation = ?
                                         WHERE user_id = ?")) {
        $update_stmt->bind_param('ss', $presentation, $user_id);
    }
    if ($update_stmt->execute() == false) {
        $success = 0;
    }
    $update_stmt->close();
```

And to output after fetching:

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($profile['presentation']); ?></p>
```

It is stored as this in the database:

```
This is line 1\r\n\r\nThis is line 3\r\nThis is line 4
```

And displayed on the page as:

```
This is line 1rnrnThis is line 3rnThis is line 4
```

What I want is the presentation to be displayed *as it was submitted by the user with the newlines preserved, cleaned of any HTML and safe to be stored* in the database.

I have tried strip_tags, stripcslashes etc but I still can't get it to work..

Someone who might be able to help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could translate them into their respective escape sequences using str_replace before passing the string through nl2br().  This is an example:

```
$profile = nl2br(str_replace('\\r\\n', "\r\n", $profile['presentation']));
```

Comment: So it was as easy as that. I believe that solved the issue. Thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with your project.